# how to parametrize a database in a distributed query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to define the database as a variable in a query like this:

```
insert into Database1.dbo.Table1
select * from Database2.dbo.Table1
```

In my case all the databases have the same schema.

I can do with dynamic sql of course, but is it a way to have a syntax like:

```
insert into Database1.dbo.Table1
select * from @ChosenDatabase.dbo.Table1
```

?

Thanks

Comment: Dynamic SQL is the only possibility if you are pushing your queries directly to the DB.

Comment: what is question here you can do this with help of dynamic sql ..

Comment: @sandeeprawat i ask because i wanted to know whether it was possible to do without dynamic sql, since the script needs to be run from management studio and  while from software it is fine to use dynamic sql, from management studio it is trickier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible; You have to use Dynamic SQL :

```
DECLARE @SQLQuery varchar(300)
DECLARE @TableName varchar(100)
SET @TableName = ChosenDatabase.dbo.Table1
SET @SQLQuery = 'INSERT INTO Database1.dbo.Table1 SELECT * FROM ' + @TableName  
EXEC(@SQLQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Declare @dbname varchar(200)

Declare @sql varchar(1000)

now comes dynamic sql

set @sql='select * from '@dbname+'dbo.yourtable';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use dynamic sql

```
declare @ChosenDatabase varchar(100)='dbname'
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL= 'select * from '+ @ChosenDatabase+'.dbo.Customer'
--SELECT @SQL
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
```